# Canceling form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In the following code I tried to close the popup form which was from jquery and not to submit action when I click no button and delete when I click delete. It worked earlier but now even when I click cancel the form submits to the contoller and delete action is done. What has gone wrong? how can I make the cancel button close the popup but not submit.help please!

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <fieldset style="width:70%;">


                            @Html.Hidden("CnoType", Model.CnoType, Model)


                               <b> Description: </b>

                                @Html.DisplayFor(Desc=>Model.CNoDesc)<br />

                                <b> Prefix:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                @Html.DisplayFor(Prefix=>Model.CnoPrefix)<br />

                            <b>Is Enable</b> &nbsp;
                           @Html.CheckBox("IsEnable", Model.IsEnable, Model)



            </fieldset>

            <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Delete" />

             <button class="Close">Cancel</button>

        }
```

Here is my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("dialog")
                    .attr("id", $(this)
                    .attr("data-dialog-id"))
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                        minWidth: 500,
                        minHeight: 100,
                        resizable: false,
                        close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                        modal: true
                    })

                    .load(this.href);
                });

                $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
                });
            });

</script>
```

e.preventDefault() does not seem to be working

Comment: which plugin you are using for the popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".Close").click(function(){
         return false;  //prevents default action (submit)
     });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".Close").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();  //prevents default action (submit)
     });
});
```

Comment: I have posted my jquery above.Please check

Comment: Unless there's a transcription error, your selector looks wrong.  The class is "Close" not "close".

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your jquery page load method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".Close").click(function(){
         $.colorbox.close();  // if you are using colorbox for generating the popup.
     });
});
```